# mongoose - add and remove object from 3 level deep array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, nested

Hello I have a schema like this

```
    account: {
    blogPosts: [{
        title: String,
        text: String,
        date: String,
        author: String,
        editDate: String,
        comments: [{
            username: String,
            text: String,
            date: String,
            likes: Array
        }]
    }]
},
```

What I am trying to do is when a user likes a comment on a blogPost I want to push their username to the likes array. First I have to find the post to access the comments relating to that post. Then I have to find the comment they liked and push there name to the likes array.

So this is what I came up with so far

```
   app.post('/server-activity/like-blog-comment', (req, res) => {
    const username = req.user.account.username;
    const blogAuthor = req.body.blogAuthor;
    const blogId = req.body.blogId;
    const commentId = req.body.commentId;

    userCollection.findOne({
        'account.username': blogAuthor
    }, function(err, obj) {
        if (err) return err;

        for (var i = 0; i < obj.account.blogPosts.length; i++) {
            if (blogId == obj.account.blogPosts[i]._id) {

                for (var x = 0; x < obj.account.blogPosts[i].comments.length; x++) {
                    if (commentId == obj.account.blogPosts[i].comments[x]._id) {

                        if(obj.account.blogPosts[i].comments[x].likes.indexOf(username) === -1){
                        obj.account.blogPosts[i].comments[x].likes.unshift(username);
                        obj.save(err => {
                            if (err) return err
                            res.send('success');
                        });
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    });
});
```

that works as expected but It's pretty messy I am wondering if there is a way to do this with just mongoose?

Also for unliking a comment it works almost the same way except I splice the user from the likes array like below

```
    app.post('/server-activity/unlike-blog-comment', (req, res) => {
    const username = req.user.account.username;
    const blogAuthor = req.body.blogAuthor;
    const blogId = req.body.blogId;
    const commentId = req.body.commentId;

    userCollection.findOne({
        'account.username': blogAuthor
    }, function(err, obj) {
        if (err) return err;

        for (var i = 0; i < obj.account.blogPosts.length; i++) {
            if (blogId == obj.account.blogPosts[i]._id) {

                for (var x = 0; x < obj.account.blogPosts[i].comments.length; x++) {
                    if (commentId == obj.account.blogPosts[i].comments[x]._id) {

                        const index = obj.account.blogPosts[i].comments[x].likes.indexOf(username) 

                        if(obj.account.blogPosts[i].comments[x].likes[index] === username){
                        obj.account.blogPosts[i].comments[x].likes.splice(index, 1);
                        obj.save(err => {
                            if (err) return err
                            res.send('success');
                        });
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    });
});
```

So is there a way to do both of these operations with just plain mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `async` library or any `callback function` to avoid `callback hell`

```
    app.post('/server-activity/unlike-blog-comment', (req, res) => {
    const username = req.user.account.username;
    const blogAuthor = req.body.blogAuthor;
    const blogId = req.body.blogId;
    const commentId = req.body.commentId;

    userCollection.findOne({
        'account.username': blogAuthor
    }, function(err, obj) {
        if (err) return err;

        async.each(obj.account.blogPosts,function(i,calllback){
           if (blogId == i._id) {
              async.each(i.comments,function(x,callback){
                   if (commentId == x._id) {
                        const index = x.likes.indexOf(username);
                        if(x.likes[index] === username){
                           x.likes.splice(index, 1);
                           obj.save(err => {
                        if (err) return err
                        res.send('success');
                         });
                        }
                   }
               });
           }
        });
   });
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! Not exactly what I wanted but still better then what I had i'll accept it